# Ubuntu 22.04 AWS import initramfs/initrd issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws

I'm working on a multi-cloud deployment for Ubuntu 22.04 and I haven't done this since 16.04, I've got a raw image created with QEMU, and I'm trying to get it into AWS, the import is telling me:

> ```
>   "StatusMessage": "ClientError: We were unable to read your import's initramfs/initrd to determine what drivers your import requires to run in EC2.",
> ```

There's not much in AWS to to go off of, I don't mind debugging it as a black-box, just wondering **where I should go looking for potential problems on the base image**.  This should be a legacy-boot, not UEFI deployment and I made sure AWS understood that. (I'd have used UEFI, but I have to do a PXE deployment onto hardware the doesn't quite support it as well as the virtual stuff)

But I had no problem importing this image into hyper-v, virtualbox or Vmware.

I did notice 22.04 isn't on the list for VM Imports, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/prerequisites.html  but that seems a little suspicious, not sure if anybody can comment on to the timeline when Amazon gets around to letting people import new OS'es.

Comment: I was having the same issue. Found this and used import-snapshot and I am having no issues using Ubuntu 22.04 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564150/aws-error-while-creating-ami-from-ubuntu-error-initramfs-initrd

Comment: @kc_it yeah, that was my answer on SO!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Amazon support about this as I was getting the same error with a 22.04 import.  They said 22.04 isn't supported and to use 20.04.  They didn't have an estimate when 22.04 would be supported.